# segmentation fault - Doubly Linked List

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I am implementing a doubly linked list that works similar to a queue. So when I add nodes to the list (e.g 5 nodes) and empty the list and try to add a new node to the list, it gives me a segmentation fault (core dumped). I don't know why it is doing that.  Can you explain?

#### linkedlist.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node{
    int d;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
}node;

typedef struct linkedlist{
    int size;
    struct node *first;
    struct node *last;
}linkedlist;
```

#### linkedlist.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "linkedlist.h"

linkedlist* createList(){
    linkedlist* myList = (linkedlist*)calloc(1,sizeof(linkedlist));
    myList->first = NULL;
    myList->last = NULL;
    myList->size =0;

    return myList;
}

static node* createNode(int n){
    node *myNode = (node*)calloc(1,sizeof(node));

    myNode->d = n;

    myNode->prev = NULL;
    myNode->next = NULL;

    return myNode;
}

void insertNode(linkedlist* l, int num){
    node *temp, *newNode;

    newNode = createNode(num);

    if (l->size == 0){
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->prev = NULL;

        l->first = newNode;
        l->last = newNode;

        l->size++;
    }
    else{
        temp = l->first;
        while (temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }   

        newNode->prev = temp;
        temp->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        l->size++;
    }
}

int deleteNode(linkedlist* l){
    node *temp = calloc(1,sizeof(node));

    if (l->first ==NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    else if (l->size ==1){

        free(l->first);
        l->first= NULL;
        l->last = NULL;

        l->size--;
    }
    else if (l->size > 1){
        temp = l->first;
        l->first = temp->next;          

        free(temp);
    }
}

void display(linkedlist *l){
    node *temp = calloc(1,sizeof(node));
    temp = l->first;

    if (temp == NULL){
        printf("The list is empty\n");
    }
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("-> %d ", temp->d);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main(){

    linkedlist *myList = createList();

    int choice, temp=0, numb;
    printf("(1) Insert \n (2) Delete \n");

    for (temp; temp<10; temp++){
    printf("Choice :");
    scanf ("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice) {
        case 1: {
            printf("Enter a Number: ");
            scanf("%d", &numb);
            insertNode(myList, numb);
            display(myList);
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
             deleteNode(myList);
            display(myList);
            break;

        }
    }

    }       
}
```

Comment: You're memory leaks in `deleteNode()` and `display()` are *not* good. C++ is not Java. And if you want to discover that fault, perhaps run this under a debugger like **gdb**.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html). for a gdb segfault example. Then you can get closer to where the segfault arises

Comment: You might as well use `malloc()` as `calloc()` in `createNode()` and `createList()` since you initialize all the members in your functions anyway.  However, that has nothing to do with the presence or absence of a core dump.  You should also check that the allocation succeeds before initializing the data.

Comment: The code in `insertNode()` that seeks through the list is ... well, inefficient and makes a mockery of having the `last` member in the list structure.  You're treating it as if you've only got a singly-linked list.  You should be able to go directly to `l->last` and add the new node immediately after it; that's the only point in having `last`.  Since you don't set `last` in `insertNode()` with a non-empty list, you can't use it after you have more than one entry in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are not decrementing the size of the list when `l->size > 1`:

```
int deleteNode(linkedlist* l){

    node *temp = calloc(1,sizeof(node));

    if (l->first ==NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    else if (l->size ==1){
        free(l->first);
        l->first= NULL;
        l->last = NULL;
        l->size--;               \\ <--- Here is OK
    }
    else if (l->size > 1){
        temp = l->first;
        l->first = temp->next;          
        free(temp);
                                \\ <--- Here should have another l->size--
    }
}
```

You could also just move the decrement instruction out of the if statement.

Answer (score -1):

I did not go through your program completely but from what i have seen here

```
 linkedlist *myList = createList();
```

You are initializing your list at the start and then the delete node

```
int deleteNode(linkedlist* l){

    node *temp = calloc(1,sizeof(node));

    if (l->first ==NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    else if (l->size ==1){
        free(l->first);
        l->first= NULL;
        l->last = NULL;
        l->size--;
    }
    else if (l->size > 1){
        temp = l->first;
        l->first = temp->next;          
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

frees entire list

then when you do insert node

```
void insertNode(linkedlist* l, int num){
   node *temp, *newNode;

   newNode = createNode(num);

    if (l->size == 0){
       newNode->next = NULL;
       newNode->prev = NULL;
       l->first = newNode;
       l->last = newNode;
       l->size++;
    }
    else{
       temp = l->first;
       while (temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }   
        newNode->prev = temp;
        temp->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        l->size++;
    }
}
```

l->size may be creating segfault, you need to fix your deletion logic or insert logic

Comment: How does `deleteNode()` free the "entire list" ? I see no `free()` of the `l` parameter either directly or otherwise. There is a definite memory leak (the `calloc()` is completely unnecessary) but I see no freeing of the actual `linkedlist *l` passed into the function.

Comment: deleteNode() will not free the entire list but in the question its mentioned that the test case is about creating a list of 5 nodes and then deleting all nodes and then inserting a new node again thats where the problem is besides I agree there is memory leak anyway